# awk, sed, grep specific strings from a file in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, grep

Here is part of the complete file that I am trying to filter:

```
 Hashmode: 13761 - VeraCrypt PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA256 + XTS 512 bit + boot-mode (Iterations: 200000)

Speed.#2.........:     2038 H/s (56.41ms) @ Accel:128 Loops:32 Thr:256 Vec:1
Speed.#3.........:     2149 H/s (53.51ms) @ Accel:128 Loops:32 Thr:256 Vec:1
Speed.#*.........:     4187 H/s
```

The aim is to print the following:
`13761 VeraCrypt PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA256 4187 H/s`

Here is what I tried.
The complete file is called complete.txt

```sh
cat complete.txt | grep Hashmode | awk '{print $2,$4,$5}' > mode.txt
```

Output:

```
 13761 VeraCrypt PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA256
```

Then:

```sh
cat complete.txt | grep Speed.# | awk '{print $2,$3}' > speed.txt
```

Output:

```
 4187 H/s
```

Then:

```sh
paste mode.txt speed.txt
```

The issue is that the lines do not match. There are approx 200 types of modes to filter within the file 'complete.txt'

I also have a feeling that this can be done using a much simpler command with `sed` or awk.

Comment: Your formatting seems slightly erratic; should there really be spaces in front of and behind the output? The commands also don't produce what you claim they produce (in particular, the `Speed` command should fetch all the lines which match in your sample).

Comment: As an aside, you want to avoid the [useless `cat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat) and probably also the [useless `grep`.](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep)

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are looking for something like the following.

```sh
awk '/Hashmode:/ { if(label) print label, speed; label = $2 " " $4 " " $5 }
  /Speed\.#/ { speed = $2 " " $ 3 }
END { if (label) print label, speed }' complete.txt
```

We match up the `Hashmode` line with the *last* `Speed.#` line which follows, then print when we see a new Hashmode, or reach end of file.  (Failing to print the last one is a common beginner bug.)

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/Hashmode:/{:a;x;s/^[^:]*: (\S+) -( \S+ \S+ ).*\nSpeed.*:\s*(\S+ \S+).*/\1\2\3/p;x;h;d};H;$!d;ba' file
```

If a line contains `Hashmode`, swap to the hold space and using pattern matching, manipulate its contents to the desired format and print, swap back to the pattern space, copy the current line to the hold space and delete the current line.

Otherwise, append the current line to the hold space and delete the current line, unless the current line is the last line in the file, in which case process the line as if it contained `Hashmode`.

N.B. The first time `Hashmode` is encountered, nothing is output. Subsequent matches and the end-of-file condition will be the only times printing occurs.